# How do to redirect to the last visited page using PHP?

Tags: php

What I'm looking for is a mechanism to restore the last visited page.

For example, if the user opens the URL www.example.org, then goes to www.example.org/a.html and close the browser tab/window; and then after some arbitrarily time if decide to revisit the website, but opens the URL www.example.org/b.html or www.example.org, the user must be redirected to www.example.org/a.html.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
    $cookie_name = "last_page";
    $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

    // Pregunta si la cookie ha sido creado; si no ha sido creada la crea:
    if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
        setcookie($cookie_name, $actual_link, time() + (86400 * 30));
        setcookie("redirected", 1);
        echo "<br/>first visited<br/>";
    } else {
        if (strlen($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]) == 0 and $_COOKIE["redirected"] == 1){
            $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] = $_COOKIE["last_page"];
            setcookie("redirected", 2);
            drupal_goto($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
        } else if (strlen($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]) !== 0 and strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], 'localhost') and $_COOKIE["redirected"] == 2){
            setcookie($cookie_name, $actual_link, time() + (86400 * 30));
            setcookie("redirected", 1);
            sleep(5);
        } 
    }
?>
```

But it does not working.

Some suggestions to achieve that objetive?

Comment: Is there any problem with what you've got so far?
It looks ok to me, apart from that I doubt this behaviour is really user-friendly. If there are pages the user should not enter your site at, a htaccess rule could be simpler.

Comment: @Jeff This is what is happening: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwpnpfd5tqn48nu/Redirecci%C3%B3n%20-%2020160919%20-%20Operaci%C3%B3n.gif?dl=0 The next time I open a new tab and try to visit http://localhost:8484/drupal7/ the user does not take to the last open tab, i.e., http://localhost:8484/drupal7/user/register

Comment: sorry, the video is a bit confusing (to figure out when it's redirecting, when it's not, if it's only redirecting to wrong page,...).
Can you explain the exact steps to produce unwanted behaviour (and what the result is)? EDIT: ok, I think I got it....hang on

Comment: @Jeff First I go to http://localhost:8484/drupal7/ so the code creates the cookie `last_page`, next, I go to http://localhost:8484/drupal7/user/register, close the tab. Now If I put http://localhost:8484/drupal7, the user would be redirected to http://localhost:8484/drupal7/user/register but the user is redirected to http://localhost:8484/drupal7.

Comment: hm.... I can't find an obvios error.
My suggestion is to log out (echo) the cookies in every step to find the error.